# React router keep rendering unmatched route inside matched route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

i have following the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match)
version: "^5.2.0",

here's my code:

```
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'
import PublicRoute from './PublicRoute'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import NotFound from 'page/NotFound'
import Router from './router'

const RouteWrapper = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
    {
      Router.map((props) => (
        props.private ? (
          <PrivateRoute key={props.path} {...props} />
        ) : (
          <PublicRoute key={props.path} {...props} />
        )
      ))
    }
  </React.Fragment>
)

export default RouteWrapper
```

in App.jsx

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ScrollReset, AuthGuard } from 'utils'
import RouteWrapper from 'router/route_wrapper'

const App = () => (
  <Router basename='/'>
    <ScrollReset />
    <AuthGuard />
    <Switch>
      <RouteWrapper />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

export default App
```

NotFound.jsx:

```
const NotFound = () => (
  <div>Page Not Found</div>
)

export default NotFound
```

i create not found route for handling error when route not match, but the route always rendered in every matched route.
any suggestion?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thxnE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not found route path should be the last one while checking if any route path is matched.

```
    import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'
    import PublicRoute from './PublicRoute'
    import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    import NotFound from 'page/NotFound'
    import Router from './router'
    
    const RouteWrapper = () => (
      <React.Fragment>
        {
          Router.map((props) => (
            props.private ? (
              <PrivateRoute key={props.path} {...props} />
            ) : (
              <PublicRoute key={props.path} {...props} />
            )
          ))
        }
      <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
    
    export default RouteWrapper
```

Comment: its only move the not found component to the bottom